# cocos2dx how random with percentage?

Tags: random, percentage

Is there anyway to random object with percentage? 
For example: i have an CCArray with 3 CCSprite: spriteA, spriteB, spriteC.

spriteA = 30% chance to appear, spriteB = 60% chance to appear, spriteC = 10% chance to appear.

```
I have try this but it seem wrong:

int r = arc4random() % 100;
if (r >= 0 && r < 10) 
{
   CCLOG("spriteC appear");
} 
else if (r >= 10 && r < 30) 
{
   CCLOG("spriteA appear");
} 
else if (r >= 30 && r < 100) 
{
   CCLOG("spriteB appear");
}
```

Comment: because the arc4random() just random a number(in this case 1 - 100), and sometime it random from 0 to 30 many time continuous cause it not right with the chance 10% or 30%.

Comment: put int r = abs(arc4random() % 100); to avoid negative values, the code works perfectly

Comment: no it not right the chance 10%, it appear too much! sometime spriteC appear more than spriteB.